# Find a point on a plane given the plane's normal and a point along that normal

Tags: math, graphics, vector, 3d

I am given a point (Px,Py,Pz) and a normal vector (Nx,Ny,Nz).  I have to find the purple point  (Tx,Ty,Tz) in this diagram:

[illustration http://snag.gy/kLvIZ.jpg](http://snag.gy/kLvIZ.jpg)

The black line is a plane that intersects the origin (0,0,0) and is perpendicular to the normal.  How can I find T?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I was actually specifically looking for the distance D between P and T. I think the answer to that is simply just `dot(N,P)`.  I got there after solving for D in these equations: `T=P-N*D` and `dot(N,T)=0`.